# Swift optional parameter not unwrapped

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a function with a optional parameter(position). I test for it to be nil but still Xcode shows me an error: "Value of optional type Int? not unwrapped" and suggests me to use "!" or "?".

```
var entries = [String]()

func addEntry(text: String, position: Int?) {
    if(position == nil) {
        entries.append(text)
    } else {
        entries[position] = text
    }
}
```

Im new to Swift and don't understand why this isn't ok. Within this if-clause the compiler should be 100% sure that position is defined, or?

Comment: Which line gives you that error?

Comment: `entries[position] = text` for "position"

Comment: Take a look at *Optional Binding* in [the Swift language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330).

Comment: just because you do an if-check that does not change the value and type of the things you check, would be terrible if it does... Therefore position is *still* of type `Int?`

Comment: well if you just want remove the error then remove ? from func addAttachment(text: String, position: Int?)

Comment: I want to have position optional. If using `addAttachment("123")` it should use append. If `addAttachment("123", 3)` it should add on array position 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to code this properly:

```
func addEntry(text: String, position: Int?) {
    // Safely unwrap the value
    if let position = position {
        entries[position] = text
    } else {
        entries.append(text)
    }
}
```

or:

```
func addEntry(text: String, position: Int?) {
    if position == nil {
        entries.append(text)
    } else {
        // Force unwrap since you know it isn't nil
        entries[position!] = text
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But why doesn't the compiler already know it isn't nil since i made an if clause? (referring to your second code)

Comment: `position == nil`this does not compare a value with nil, but an optional that might hold a nil with nil. with `position!` or `if let position = position` you are accessing this value. you *unwrap* it @Mick

Comment: I would avoid the second example, force unwrapping a `Optional`, if at all possible. Sometime down the road you might remove the check and expose a possible runtime bug. Optional unwrapping is safer because the compiler can check for it at compile time.

Comment: @ColGraff This is why I put the better solution first.

Comment: @rmaddy The second example is quite a Swift anti pattern. I wouldn't show it to new learners.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you checked for `nil` you still haven’t converted the `Int?` into an `Int` to use as an index. To do that you need to unwrap the `Optional`:

```
var entries = [String]()

func addEntry(text: String, position: Int?) {
  // guard against a nil position by attempting to
  // unwrap it with optional binding
  guard
    // test for nil and unwrap using optional binding
    let unwrappedPosition = position,
    // make sure the position isn't 
    // past the end of the array
    unwrappedPosition < entries.count else {
      // can't unwrap it or 
      // it's out of bounds,
      // append it
      entries.append(text)
      return
  }

  // successfully unwrapped, set item at index
  entries[unwrappedPosition] = text
}
```