# Why unwrap a variable that can not be nil?

Tags: swift, unwrap

New to Swift and saw code from Standford open course of Swift programming as below:

```
if pending != nil {
    acccumulator = pending!.binaryFunction(pending!.firstOperand,acccumulator)
    pending = nil
}
```

As I learn about unwrapping, `pending`, in this case, is ensured not to be nil inside `if` block, then why should I use `!` to unwrap pending while using it?

Comment: Related: [Swift optional parameter not unwrapped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290202/swift-optional-parameter-not-unwrapped)

Answer (score 4):

Because the `if` check has no bearing on the code inside the block. In this example, you should instead use a `let`, like so:

```
if let nonNilPending = pending {
    acccumulator = nonNilPending.binaryFunction(nonNilPending.firstOperand,acccumulator)
    pending = nil
}
```

That way you avoid the force-unwraps.

Comment: I'm awaring of this though I am still confused for Swift can infer many things, and why does its compiler is not able to figure out impossibility of nil for an optional variable within such situation? I assume concept of 'optional' in Swift is kind of ’null‘ in C++ ...Thus if could prevents inside block executing with nil or void or null variable.

Answer (score 4):

Even though you know that `pending` is not `nil`, its type remains optional. The compiler does not treat it differently in various contexts (i.e. inside and outside `if`) so you have to use `!` operator in both places.

Swift does offer you a mechanism to check for `nil` and unwrap in a single go with an [`if let` construct](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html), which presents a convenient alternative to forced unwrapping.

Answer (score 2):

Because even if you're in that if block, the compiler doesn't know that the variable is "unwrapped". On top of that, using the force unwrap is a bad idea. You would be better off unwrapping the variable in an if conditional and then using the constant you set it to. For example:

```
if let unwrappedPending = pending {
    accumulator = unwrappedPending.binaryFunction(...)
    pending = nil
}
```

By setting the optional `pending` to the constant, you're conditionally unwrapping it. Then you can use the constant with the security of knowing that the constant is not nil and you don't have to use `!`